# A surprisingly simple determinant

Tags: taylor-expansion, determinant, fourier-series

Let $a_k^{(n)}$ be the $n$-vector whose components are the first $n$ non-null coefficients of the Taylor expansion of $\sin(k x)$ around $0$. Define the matrix $A^{(n)}$ as the matrix whose rows are the vectors $a_1^{(n)};a_2^{(n)}\dots a_n^{(n)}$, i.e. the $k$-th row of $A^{(n)}$ is the vector $a_k^{(n)}$. Then $A^{(n)}$ has determinant given by
$$\det A^{(n)} = (-1)^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\,,$$
i.e. $\det A^{(1)} = 1$, $\det A^{(2)} = -1$, $\det A^{(3)} = -1$, $\det A^{(4)} = 1$, $\det A^{(5)} = 1$ and so on.

To clarify the first matrices are
$$A^{(1)}=\begin{pmatrix}1\end{pmatrix}\,;$$
$$A^{(2)}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -\frac{1}{6}\\2 & -\frac{4}{3}\end{pmatrix}\,;$$
$$A^{(3)}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -\frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{120}\\2 & -\frac{4}{3} & \frac{4}{15}\\ 3&-\frac{9}{2} & \frac{81}{40}\end{pmatrix}\,\dots$$

I guess there must be a simple explanation for such an easy determinant and a smart way to prove it. Any idea?

I came across this problem when thinking about some possible answer to a question asking for some intuitive way behind the fact that the trigonometric functions forms a basis. My idea was that one may show that the monomials $x^{2k+1}$ can be founded by eliminating term by term the unnecessary terms from the Taylor expansion of $\sin$. So I've started by looking at the truncated Taylor series and I found this matrices, whose inverse are the coefficient to find monomials from linear combination of the truncated expansions of $\sin(kx)$. My idea is that actually the fact that the determinant is $1$ may be somehow linked to the fact that the Fourier transform is an isometry, and to the extension of this fact on subspaces of $L^2$ with of polynomials of finite degree $<n$. But maybe I'm hallucinating...

Comment: I am confused.  Is the definition of $A^{(n)}$ as follows: the $m$-th row of $A^{(n)}$ is $$\left[a_1^{(m)}\;\;a_2^{(m)}\;\;\ldots\;\; a_n^{(m)}\right]\,?$$  As you have written, all rows of $A^{(n)}$ should be the same.

Comment: It seems $A^{(n)}=(a_{i,j})$ with $a_{i,j}=\frac{(-1)^{j+1}i^{2j-1}}{(2j-1)!}$ and $i,j=1,2,\dots,n$.

Comment: @ECL Please fix your definition of $A^{(n)}$.

Comment: @Batominovski I've edited, I hope it's clearer.

Comment: @ECL  No, you defined $a_k^{(n)}$ to be a coefficient.  It is not a row vector.  I think my suggestion in the first comment is what you meant.

Comment: You're right, I had forgot a "s" for "coefficients" but I agree that it was a misleading sentence. In my head they were vectors...

Comment: @PeterForeman yep, you're right, I'll fix it

Comment: @ECL  You are not listening to me.  Your new definition of $A^{(n)}$ makes no sense.  Note that $a_n^{(k)}$ is now a vector of length $k$.  Therefore, $A^{(n)}$ has $n$ rows but the $k$-th row has only $k$ entries.  I gave you a good suggestion in my first comment, but you threw it out and then wrote a definition that made no sense.  You moved from one wrong definition to another wrong definition.  Fortunately, other people picked up on what you wanted.  If you don't like my suggestion, use Sil's comment as a definition.

Comment: Ok, sorry again, you're right. And yes of course you're first comment was right, just I wanted the $a_k^{n}$ to be vectors (I founded it clearer, but seeing all the mess I made I was probably wrong), that's why I don't have just copied it into my question. Thanks for pointing out all my mistakes. Now it "should" make sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that
$$A^{(3)}=\pmatrix{1&1&1\\2&2^3&2^5\\3&3^3&3^5}\pmatrix{1&&\\&-1/6&\\&&1/120}
=\pmatrix{1&&\\&2&\\&&3}\pmatrix{1&1&1\\1&2^2&2^4\\1&3^2&3^4}\pmatrix{1&&\\&-1/6&\\&&1/120}$$
a product of a Vandermonde matrix and two diagonal matrices. There's a well-known
formula for the Vandermonde determinant.

This pattern persists.

Comment: I'm quite interested to see how the result for the Vandermonde determinant can be used to simplify to the given formula. It's still seems to be a complicated product involving the differences of the squares.

Comment: Differences of squares factor! What you should do is to consider $\det(A^{(n+1)})/A^{(n)}$. Oh, and you should consider $\sinh$ rather than $\sin$ to get rid of those pesky but unimportant minus signs.

Comment: True, nice thanks!